# Zeppelin alternative for K-V store

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Any alternative for checking key-value entries while debugging the Ignite application? Zeppelin can be able to do only SQL querying. Visor command -> modify -get -c=CName is very tedious to work on and also can't get entries by wildcard searching of keys. Or is there any way we can query the K-V store via SQL Queries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

1)REST

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#get-and-remove

2)Create the thick JAVA, .NET, C++ clients that will use native cache API

3)Node JS client:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/nodejs/examples/CachePutGetExample.js

4)Python client:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/python-thin-client-key-value

5)PHP client:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/php-thin-client-key-value

Probably I missed some integrations.

Also as I know Zeppelin supports cacheAPI using Scala syntax:

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/ignite.html

```
val cache: IgniteCache[AffinityUuid, String] = ignite.cache("words")
```

And the final way. You can add query entity to your cache and run the queries like next:

```
select _key, _val from table;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand the final one you said regarding _key, _value sql querying. Can we do SQL querying on K-V store?

Comment: _key and _val are statements that should be mapped to K-V values for the cache. You can configure the following for your cache - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#query-configuration-using-queryentity. After that, it will be possible to use them.